# Hibernate HQL query by using like operator

Tags: hibernate, hql, sql-like

Seu the following mapping

```
@Entity
public class User {

    private Integer id;

    @Id;
    private Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

}
```

Notice id is an Integer. Now i need this HQL query by using like operator

```
Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User u where u.id like :userId");
```

ATT: IT IS **like** operator NOT **=** (equals operator)

Then i use

```
List<User> userList = query.setParameter("userId", userId + "%").list();
```

But does not work because Hibernate complains IllegalArgumentException occured calling getter of User.id

Even when i use

```
query.setString("userId", userId + "%");
```

It does not work

What should i use to pass the query ?

Comment: What database engine you are using?

Comment: @Arthur - not answering your question (seems you've figured it out by yourself anyway) but I've just got to ask - why? I'm genuinely interested - what use case do you have that requires LIKE comparison for what seems to be a surrogate key?

Comment: @ChssPly76 - Hi Chss. It is a legacy system. It is tree structure where a parent group id match all children's id. For instance, if i have a group id = 22100 and i want to retrieve its children's, by matching 221 prefix, i use >>> like '221%'.

Comment: @Arthur - I see. Considering that the underlying column is numeric (and, being a PK, likely indexed) you're likely to get a better performance doing numeric comparison. E.g. for your example above, you'd do `where userId > 22100 and userId < 22200`. Depending on your database engine and table size the difference may be quite drastic (because index will be used here but won't be used for LIKE)

Comment: @ChssPly76 Thanks for your reply. It is a really good idea. In that case, i think i need to use a regex to retrieve its prefix. But there is some limitations because AT SOME CASES i need to retrieve some children, not all. So your solution may not work as expected.

Comment: @ChssPly76 I would use a regex to retrieve its prefix (221) and suffix (00). Then i need to get the next prefix (222). And then, compare both values as proposed.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

According to Hibernate reference:

> str() is used for converting numeric or temporal values to a readable string

So when i use

```
from User u where str(u.id) like :userId
```

It works fine

Comment: Yes it is. str() gave me the solution.
I struggled wtih same issue because my entity class has LONG field. I used Hibernate like operator and It gave me cast exception. Solution found with Hiberanate str() method and i used hibernate queries. Please find sample query. select b.billNumber from Bill b where str(b.billNumber) like :billNumber").setString("billNumber,your_parameter).list();

Answer (score 7):

Well, LIKE operator is usually used with textual data i.e. with VARCHAR or CHAR columns, and you have numeric `id` column (INTEGER).

Maybe you could try to map `id` field also as string and use that field in query. This may or may not work depending on your database engine. Note that you should handle all updates via `setId()` and consider `idAsString` field to be read-only.

```
@Entity
public class User {

    private Integer id;
    private String idAsString;

    @Id;
    private Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    private void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private String getIdAsString() {
       return this.idAsString;
    }

    private void setIdAsString(String idAsString) {
       this.idAsString = idAsString;
    }
}
```

Then the query would be:

```
Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User u where u.idAsString like :userId");
List<User> userList = query.setParameter("userId", userId + "%").list();
```